# Pressing print screen results in a completely white screenshot?

Tags: 13.04, screenshot

Suddenly today, any screenshots taken with <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> have turned all white. All the screenshots come in as plain white sheets.

I had a similar error in 12.10 earlier where they had turned black! Now in 13.04 they are white. I did take some screenshots yesterday and they were fine. It changed today.

What might be wrong?

Comment: Does this happen only with `gnome-screenshot-tool` ? Do you reproduce the same thing when you use e.g. Shutter ? I suspect that it is the white effect to blame while the screenshot is being taken.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this problem, and there seems to be several other (unsolved) threads in various places about this affecting 13.4.

Many also have problems with shutter, suggesting this might be a deeper bug?
One workaround that does work for me is the imagemagick import command:

```
apt-get install imagemagick    
import path/to/savehere.png
```

(then click the window you want to capture)